# How to set VAGRANT_CWD to default?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, git-bash

I setx VAGRANT_CWD to some directory (let's say it's /dir) and now vagrant isn't working properly. I have a Vagrantfile in that directory /dir, and after running that VM I try to create another one in another directory by running the following code:

```
mkdir machine1
cd machine1
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
```

However, it seems like VAGRANT_CWD refers again to /dir instead of /dir/machine1 because it gives the following error:

```
`Vagrantfile` already exists in this directory. Remove it before running `vagrant init`.
```

Therefore, I think I need to set VAGRANT_CWD to its default value. What is this value and how do I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should unset the variable :

```
unset VAGRANT_CWD
```

so that vagrant will use the current directory (`machine1`) to create the new VM.

By default, Vagrant uses the current directory you are in, so if you just want to have the vagrant files created within the current directory you should not set at all the variable

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it just needed such a simple tweek :)

Comment: yep, hopefully sometimes it does not have to be too complicated :)

Comment: Wait! After I exited Git Bash and entered again to do some more stuff, this isn't working anymore and this happens: 

$ vagrant ssh
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The working directory for Vagrant doesn't exist! This is the
specified working directory:

~/.

$ echo $VAGRANT_CWD
~/.

Comment: what if you do `env | grep VAGRANT_CWD` did you set the variable in your bash or something ? by default the variable is not set

Comment: As you can see, when unset VAGRANT_CWD became ~/. which is not allowed anymore...

Comment: no when you unset it has no value so it uses the current directory - do you have other vagrant variables set ?

Comment: That didn't change anything. And yes. I set the variable in the bash I believe

Comment: I had VAGRANT_HOME set, but I unset that one too

Comment: why do you want to set in the bash ? you can then have only 1 VM. you generally do in a case by case

Comment: well vagrant home is the directory for box and stuff, so this can be set